# Accessing data from a BoundField of Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a GridView like this

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv_FilesList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" onrowcommand="gv_FilesList_RowCommand">
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="f_Id" Visible="false" HeaderText="File Name" />
  </Columns>  
  <Columns>
   <asp:BoundField DataField="f_Name" HeaderText="File Name" />
  </Columns>                                      
  <Columns>
    <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Link" Text="Download" CommandName="DownloadFile" HeaderText="Download" />
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Now when I click on the download Button, how can I get the corresponding f_Id in order to get the related data from Database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code should work, tested on my local.

First, add [DataKeyNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames.aspx) to your GridView.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv_FilesList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" onrowcommand="gv_FilesList_RowCommand" DataKeyNames="f_Id">
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="f_Id" Visible="false" HeaderText="File Name" />
  </Columns>  
  <Columns>
   <asp:BoundField DataField="f_Name" HeaderText="File Name" />
  </Columns>                                      
  <Columns>
    <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Link" Text="Download" CommandName="DownloadFile" HeaderText="Download" />
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Then, access [DataKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeys.aspx) from codebehind.

```
protected void gv_FilesList_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "DownloadFile")
    {
        //row index
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

        //retrieve f_Id    
        int f_Id = Convert.ToInt32(gv_FilesList.DataKeys[index].Value);

        //download file with f_Id
        DownloadFile(f_Id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of ways to skin it, but you could access it like below:

```
void gv_FilesList_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e) {
   if(e.CommandName=="DownloadFile")
     int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
     GridViewRow row = gv_FilesList.Rows[index];
     string fileDownloadId = row.Cells[1].Text;
     //Pull from DB
}
```

---

And then add f_id, to the DataKeyNames attribute so it will store the hidden fields value.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv_FilesList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" onrowcommand="gv_FilesList_RowCommand" DataKeyNames="f_id">
```

[DataKeyNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames.aspx)

Comment: But this is will not work when I have Visible="false". And I of course dont want to show the f_id in the gridview.

Comment: Update your gridview, and add f_id to the "DataKeyNames" attribute see above.  Its a nice little hack that will make it store the hidden variable.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to your problem is described [in this thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/962862.aspx).
Basically you can access the row index in the event argument property called `CommandArgument`.