# gridview e.CommandArgument string not formatted properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i'm trying to bring a pdf from my database to my gridview and allow the user to click on it and download the pdf. I'm trying to follow the question that was solved here:

[Accessing data from a BoundField of Gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014758/accessing-data-from-a-boundfield-of-gridview)

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Input string was not in a correct format.
```

Here is my asp.net code:

```
     <Columns>
         <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ControlStyle-CssClass="savefile"/>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
             ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="event_name" HeaderText="event_name" 
             SortExpression="event_name" />

         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PDF">

   <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Button ID="Button1" ButtonType="Link" CommandName="DownloadFile" HeaderText="Download"  runat="server" Text="Button" />


    </ItemTemplate>

   <EditItemTemplate>

       <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" /> // shown only in edit mode

   </EditItemTemplate>

  </asp:TemplateField>

     </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

and the corresponding c# code:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

    if (e.CommandName == "DownloadFile")
    {


        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        string id = GridView1.DataKeys[index].Value.ToString();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
        string command = "Select pdf from table where id = @id";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(id, "id");
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.BinaryWrite((Byte[])reader[0]);

        Response.Flush();

        Response.End(); 
    }

}
```

The error line is this in my c# code:

```
int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
```

Thanks for the help in advance guys!

edit --------------------------------------------------

my button field now looks like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" ButtonType="Link" CommandName="DownloadFile" CommandArgument='<%#Container.DataItemIndex%>' HeaderText="Download"  runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

and my c# error code line:

```
int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
```

and i'm still receiving the same error.

Answer (score 4):

You're not specifying a `CommandArgument`. Therefore your error is occurring because you are attempting to convert a blank string into an integer.

Add the row index as your `CommandArgument`:

Try adding this to your `Button` control:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1"
            ButtonType="Link"
            CommandName="DownloadFile"
            CommandArgument='<%#Container.DataItemIndex%>'
            HeaderText="Download"
            runat="server"
            Text="Button" />
```

Comment: I added that to my button control and i'm still getting the same error. I also tried changing to e.Row.RowIndex and I got a different error GridViewCommandEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Row'

Comment: @user967713 See my edit. Use `CommandArgument='<%#Container.DataItemIndex%>'`

Comment: Still getting the same error. I edited the OP and showed what my button field and c# code line look like now.

Comment: @user967713 Change `e.Row.RowIndex` back to `e.CommandArgument`. Sorry my mistake, I was confusing DataBound event with RowCommand event. Only DataBound has access to `e.Row`.

Answer (score 3):

You are not assigning value to `CommandArgument` but accessing them in `RowCommand` which is cause of an error.

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" ButtonType="Link" CommandName="DownloadFile" HeaderText="Download"  runat="server" Text="Button" CommandArgument="1" />
```

You can Replace the hard coded CommandArgument value with bound value as @Curt told.

```
CommandArgument='<%#eval("DataField")'
```

Use ToString

```
int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error with even after changing the CommandArguements into  CommandArgument='<%#Container.DataItemIndex%>'